# Java Array Index Out of Bounds Exception No matter the array length

Tags: java, arrays

```
package helloworld;
public class windspeed {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int t = Integer.parseInt(args[44]); //this is the array input for temperature
        int v = Integer.parseInt(args[15]); //this is the array input for wind speed
        double x = Math.pow(v, 0.16); //this is the exponent math for the end of the equation
        if (t < 0) {
            t = t*(-1); //this is the absolute value for temperature
        }
        double w = (35.74 + 0.6215*t)+((0.4275*t - 35.75)* x); //this is the actual calculation
        if (t<=50 && v>3 && v<120) { //this is so the code runs only when the equation works
            System.out.println(w);
        }
        if (t>50 || v<3 || v>120){
            System.out.println("The wind chill equation doesn't work with these inputs, try again.");
        }

    }
}
```

This gives me an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` error. It doesn't matter what I put in the `[]` I get an error... why? and how can I fix it?

Comment: What does `System.out.println(args.length);` show in the console? (put it as the first line in the main method)

Comment: Seems like you are not using args correctly: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Comment: Add a `System.out.println(args.length)` to the top, and see what happes

Comment: You're passing in 45 args on the command line?!

Comment: The index determines which element of `args[]` to use, so it must be smaller than `args.length`. So you probably want `args[0]` and `args[1]`, and you'll execute your program with the arguments 44 and 15.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Answer (score 0):

The reason is

```
int t = Integer.parseInt(args[44]);
```

Do you have 45 arguments?

Comment: and the brckets `t[]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the way in which you are creating the arrays:

```
int t = Integer.parseInt(args[44]); //this is the array input for temperature
int v = Integer.parseInt(args[15]); //this is the array input for wind speed
```

`args` refers to the command line arguments that are passed to the `main()` method of your program. If you try to parse `args[44]` when there aren't 45 arguments (0 indexing, remember ?) you will end up assigning `null` to your array.

So, all you will later end up with is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` becuase you cannot index a null array.

```
int t[] = new int[44]; // please notice the brackets
int v[] = new int[15]; //this is the array input for wind speed
```

The above method shall suffice if all you need is the size

1. Arrays in Java are `int[] t` or `int t[]`. Either of them will do but the brackets need to be there.
2. Use `Math.abs()` to find the absolute value. Saves you the `if()`

Comment: `int t[] = Integer.parseInt(44);` and `int v[] = Integer.parseInt(15);` don't compile...

Answer (score 0):

```
int t = Integer.parseInt(args[44]); //this is the array input for temperature
int v = Integer.parseInt(args[15]); //this is the array input for wind speed
```

`args` i.e. `args` is the command line arguments for main method. Do you have 45 elements inside the `args` if not than it will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`.

To know the length please use:

```
args.length
```

Than you can proceed. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

In these lines :

```
int t = Integer.parseInt(args[44]); //this is the array input for temperature
int v = Integer.parseInt(args[15]); //this is the array input for wind speed
```

You say that you run your program with at least 45 parameters!! where on the 15. place is wind speed and on the 44. is temperature.

You probably running program with NO parameters at all or with one.

Note that if you run program with parameters : "hello world how are you" the program would have args of size 5 with having `hello` in `args[0]`, `world` in `args[1]` etc.

Answer (score -1):

What you have now is:
- take the 15th command line argument and cast to to Integer;
- take the 44th command line argument and cast it to Integer.
Are you sure that it is what you need?